# AWS Elastic Beanstalk -- Issue with rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, bundler, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have ruby 2.3.4 and bundler v 1.17.3
I tried to deploy it to elastic beanstalk using eb cli
Then I got an error:

> [Instance: i-09d1c36b765b9a656] Command failed on instance. Return
>   code: 18 Output: (TRUNCATED)...g: the running version of Bundler
>   (1.16.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3).
>   We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running
>   `gem install bundler`. Your Ruby version is 2.3.8, but your Gemfile
>   specified 2.3.4. Hook
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed.
>   For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB
>   CLI.

So I ran eb ssh:
Installed rvm and ruby 2.3.4 and made it the default
Installed bundler v 1.17.3 and made it the default

But when I ran eb deploy I get the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Logs:

> gem 'mocha', group: :test   + '[' -d /var/app/ondeck/vendor/cache
>   ']'   + bundle install   Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask
>   for sudo if it is needed, and   installing your bundle as root will
>   break this application for all non-root   users on this machine.
>   Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.16.2) is older than the
>   version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to
>   the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.   Your
>   Ruby version is 2.3.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.4
>   (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
>
> [2019-07-12T16:20:25.830Z] INFO  [9280]  - [Application update
>   app-260b-190712_161857@9/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_bundle_install.sh]
>   : Activity failed. [2019-07-12T16:20:25.830Z] INFO  [9280]  -
>   [Application update
>   app-260b-190712_161857@9/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity
>   failed. [2019-07-12T16:20:25.830Z] INFO  [9280]  - [Application update
>   app-260b-190712_161857@9/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
>   [2019-07-12T16:20:25.831Z] INFO  [9280]  - [Application update
>   app-260b-190712_161857@9] : Completed activity. Result:   Application
>   update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed

Answer (score 0):

I get this when starting fresh dev boxes because I always forget updating my init script.

What you can do is to set up a hook to reinstall bundler, it's basically script that removes & installs it back

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html

```
 #/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/01_update_bundler.sh
 #!/bin/sh
 gem uninstall bundler
 gem install bundler -v 1.17.3 # or whatever version you want
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. btw I have also added the logs to my question